# RubyでRegexp::Assemble相当の既存ライブラリは？

Tags: ruby, 正規表現, rubygems

PerlのRegexp::AssembleやRegexp::Trie、Emacs付属のregexp-optなどに相当するRubyの既存ライブラリを探しています。できればRubyGemsで。

求めるものは、いくつもの文字列から、いずれかにマッチするコンパクトな正規表現（文字列）を作るメソッドです。たとえば、`"who"` `"where"` `"when"`の3つの文字列が与えられた場合、`"who|where|when"`ではなく、`"(?:wh(?:e(?:n|re)|o))"`のような結果を期待しています。

なお、これは、作ることが目的ではなく、既存のものがあるかどうかを知りたいという質問です。そのため、上記の動作をするコード例を示す回答は、質問の意図に反しますので、念のため。

Comment: ぼくもちょうど探していましたが見つからずにここにたどり着きました。Regexp::Trieは単純だから移植したほうがはやそうではありますね。

Comment: やはりそうですよね。とりあえず[emasaka/regexp-trie-ruby](https://github.com/emasaka/regexp-trie-ruby)で作り始めました。

Comment: なんということでしょう。私も作ってリリースしてしまいました。

https://github.com/gfx/ruby-regexp_trie

https://rubygems.org/gems/regexp_trie

Comment: good! ではこのregexp_trieを回答として、質問をクローズします。

Answer (score 1):

質問へのコメントのとおり、[regexp_trie](https://rubygems.org/gems/regexp_trie)がRubyGemsに登録されました。質問をクローズします。